# looking for a parser for smali files

Tags: android, parsing, smali

It exist a parser for the .smali files? 
Let me be more explicative:
 i need to code a program.
 the input of this program is a .smali file.
this program ( thanks to the parser i'm looking for ) should catch every time a global variable is declarated.
next step add some code.
is that possible, or no parser yet exist for a similar task?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the parser that smali itself uses when reassembling the smali files.

https://github.com/JesusFreke/smali/blob/master/smali/src/main/antlr/smaliParser.g

Another option might be to use [dexlib2](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.smali%7Cdexlib2%7C2.0.3%7Cjar) directly to read in a dex file, perform the modifications you want, and write it back out.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, just for helping introduce people to the smali practices (including me) Could you point out to a step-by-step guide on how to parse smali files? That would be awesome. There is a lack of clear parse explanations out there in my opinion. For example in my case I cannot manage to parse smali to sqlite. cheers.